# Reader for PDF in iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe

When opening a PDF file that is embedded in an iframe, which PDF viewer is used? Is it the same one that is used when the browser opens a PDF file in a normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adobe Reader** is initiated by the browser when a PDF is requested. Please don't confuse with **Adobe Acrobat**. The former is free , whereas the latter one is commercial.

Comment: Thank you. Does every browser initiate Adobe Reader? Does the user need to install it? I don't want a case where the user cannot see the PDF because they don't have Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, 99% of the browsers does that. Its the most commonly used plug-in, yeah it must be installed and its not much of a big deal. If the user doesn't have the reader installed, most browsers automatically redirect to the site where the plugin can be downloaded.